# Why am I only getting 2 karma for 50 kittens?

Tags: kittens-game

I have 50 kittens, but it says I will only receive 2 karma. Shouldn't I receive 14 karma for these?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The calculation in the game is as follows:

You have **50 kittens**, this results in **15 karma kittens** (an internal calculation value). We then take the **square root of 1 plus 8 times karma kittens divided by 5**, **subtract 1** and **divide by 2**.

So:

1. **sqrt( 1 + 8 * 15 / 5 )** = **5**
2. **5 - 1** = **4**
3. **4 / 2** = **2**

Thus, you get 2 karma points.

The algorithm is explained in the [Kittens Game Wiki page about karma](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php).

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. I thought the karma and karmaKittens numbers were the same, and it was the karmaEffect that had the square root shenanigans. Beautiful, thank you!